# Updating local branch if someone made commits to the unmerged PR?

Tags: git, github

I created a branch(b1), wrote some code, pushed it(branch b1) to the remote repo, and opened a PR. Someone later added a commit to my PR. How do I update my branch(b1) locally so it is up to date with the commits made?

Comment: Just do `git pull`?

Comment: if you want to pull a specific branch then: git pull origin b1

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you have submitted a PR, you have most likely done that in your fork. Unless you have designated another person as a collaborator into your forked repo, no one else has permissions to add to your PR branch. If this is the case, they have most likely created a fork *from your repo*, and then added new commits into their copy of your branch - and then themselves raised a PR.

If the above is the case, you can follow these steps:

```
git remote add <someName> <the other person's repo>
# eg: git remote add vijay https://github.com/foo/bar.git

# This assumes that you are already in your branch (`wip-branch`)
git fetch --all
git pull -r vijay wip-branch
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^ assumes that this is branch-name on the other person's repo
```

At this point, your original commits in your branch should be earliest, followed by the commit(s) that the other person has done. You can then choose to accept and push these changes into your own repo and continue with you next set of edits.

Comment: +1 to this. I was worried about someone making a PR and then deleting their branch, but I think that's not possible while the PR is open. If it is possible, github will let you pull a PR directly. Github docs: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally. I don't think it's worth creating another answer since it's probably not needed.